# Can't get Canon scanner to work with Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: scanner

Canon DCR225 Scanner

After installing Ubuntu 18.04 (clean install) I can't get my scanner to work. I am trying to use gscan2pdf, but after it detects the scanner, the scan button is greyed out.

On my other laptop (Ubuntu 16.04) it works fine.

Any idea what can cause this?

Comment: Hi obelix, I have a Canon scanner too, although a much older model. Are you connected via USB cable or is it a networked device? Just curious, any reason you are not using Simple Scan? You can save your scans as a multiple page PDF. If you have tried Simple Scan and it didn't work, and you are using a USB connection, honestly, I would suggest just unplugging the USB cable, turning off the printer completely, turning it back on, and reconnecting. I often have to do this, sometimes in between jobs, with my Canon and it stinks,

Comment: but it's better than not being able to print or scan at all. I've ended up not being able to use my Canon in past installations where I tried messing around with other drivers, using Gutenprint, pretty much every option out there.

Answer (score 1):

so this device is probably the **DR-C225**
https://www.usa.canon.com/internet/portal/us/home/products/details/scanners/document-scanner/imageformula-dr-c225

Canon supply a driver;

go here https://www.canon-europe.com/support/products/document-scanners/dr-series/imageformula-dr-c225.aspx?type=drivers&language=EN&os=Linux%20(64-bit) and download d15106mux_Linux_v10_DRC225_DRC225W_64bit.zip

if you save it to your Downloads folder; then if you open a terminal and copy the commands below; and paste them into a terminal; (hit the ENTER key after each paste ..)

```
cd Downloads

unzip d15106mux_Linux_v10_DRC225_DRC225W_64bit.zip

cd DR-C225_LinuxDriver_1.00-4-x86_64/x86_64

sudo dpkg -i cndrvsane-drc225_1.00-4_amd64.deb
```

.. so you need your sudo password for the last command .. and that .... should ... install the driver; and then xsane or simple scan should "see" the scanner and get it to run

---

SANE, the open-source place for scanning; lists this device as **UNTESTED**; so you could help them by contacting them https://alioth-lists.debian.net/cgi-bin/mailman/listinfo/sane-devel *so you could join the mailing list*; **please help them**

Answer (score 1):

I just changed Grub line enabling USB 3 - https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2336077. Works fine.